# App crashing when trying to save to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I came across this weird bug in my app when I try to save to core data. It used to work fine until suddenly I started getting this error:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data 
change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of 
NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. Object's persistent store is 
not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator with userInfo (null)
```

I tried placing an exception breakpoint and it throws it when I try to do:

```
managedObjectContext?.save()
```

I am not sure why this is the case, I even tried resetting the simulator but I still get this error. Any ideas??

Comment: What do you mean? I don't user NSUserDefault

Comment: Are you subscribed to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` notifications anywhere?

Comment: @user3536057 Did you modify core data attributes or added some objects in it? If you did delete the application and install again.

Comment: @ff10 No I don't. How does that work?

Comment: @user3536057 I haven't changed anything. I have that but still throws this.

Comment: Haven't changed anything?

Comment: Yeah I haven't modified any attributes or entities